# Color syntax printing in SSMS 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

It seems the SSMS of Sql server 2012 cannot print the SQL statements with syntax color anymore. Is it a bug? Does it have any workaround?

Comment: "Print" as in physically print to an ink printer?

Comment: Print to a color printer. Laser or inkjet.

Comment: I've noticed this too, and while it's a minor annoyance it's not really a dealbreaker. @mrdenny has a good workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly I've never tried printing from SSMS before.  For a workaround I'd copy and paste the code into Microsoft Word (or some other editor which supports rich data, aka text with color) and print from there.

Are you really printing code that often that the color matters?

Comment: Yes, I used this trick on VS 2010 (well SSMS 2012 is actually VS 2010) until there is an extension available for C# color printing. I print code from time to time - when I need to analysis/read some complex code. Is there a way to create an "external tool" so there is no need to manually open Word every time?

Comment: Yeah, click on Tools > External Tools and point to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE" (you might need to change the 15 to 14 or 13 depending on the version of Office that you have installed, I've got 2013).

Answer (score 4):

The [color printing extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/00ec88c2-1553-47d2-8170-3c5baa0c6e44/) for Visual Studio 2010 works just fine for adding the color print ability to SSMS 2012. Download the VSIX package, and unzip into it's own directory in your to your SSMS extensions folder (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Extensions` most likely). You'll then want to modify the `extension.vsixmanifest` file -- in the `<SupportedProducts>` section add

```
      <IsolatedShell Version="1.0">ssms</IsolatedShell>
```

After that, restart SSMS, and you'll have the ability to print in color, even if it doesn't look like it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  It will successfully print in color files from a "normal" instance of VS 2010, but when used as SSMS, I still get regular B&W printing. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest verifying the change to `extension.vsixmanifest`. In addition, make sure that you unzipped the extension into its own directory within Extensions, not into the Extensions directory directly.

Comment: I downloaded `ColorPrinting.vsix` and double-clicked it, and it seems to have installed correctly.  The file `extension.vsixmanifest` exists in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Extensions\Application\\ ` and the `<IsolatedShell...` code was already in the file after install.